# App works on PC but not in Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I created an app using Unity3D. After developing it for some weeks I tried to generate an apk and test it on my SGII.

Unity returns no errors or warnings when testing the app locally, but when it runs on my phone, it doesn't work.

There are 2 buttons (1 to clock in and 1 to clock out from work). Button 1 takes the date when you clock in, and switches a boolean to allow you to clock out. When running in my phone, button 1 works fine but button 2 doesn't. The button works actually, since it returns every debug.log, but nothing else.

My code looks like this:

```
function OnGUI()
 {
GUI.skin = skin;

if(Functions.firstTime == 0)
{
        Functions.setupWiz();
}


switch(currentMenu)
{
    case 1: 

        GUI.BeginGroup(Rect(0, 0, width, height));


            if(Functions.birthday == true)
            {
                debugLog11 = "\n"+happyBirthdayMsg+", "+Functions.userName+"!";
                Functions.birthday = false;
            }


            if(GUI.Button(Rect(buttonTopHMargin,height*.1f + buttonTopVMargin, width*.24f, height*.1f), "ENTRADA", "Box"))
            {   
                if(!clockedIn && clockedOut)
                {
                    var clockIn = Functions.clockIn();
                    debugLog11 = "\nHora de entrada";
                    debugLog12 = "\n"+clockIn[3]+":"+clockIn[4]+":"+clockIn[5];
                    clockedIn = true;
                    clockedOut = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    debugLog11 = "\n"+errorMsg1;
                    debugLog12 = "\n";
                }
            }





            if(GUI.Button(Rect(width - buttonTopHMargin - width*.24f, height*.1f + buttonTopVMargin, width*.24f, height*.1f), "SALIDA", "Box"))
            {
                if(!clockedOut && clockedIn)
                {
//                  debugLog11 = clockedIn+"\n"+clockedOut;
                    Functions.clockOut();
                    var clockOut = Functions.clockOut();
                    var workedSecondsToday : Array = Functions.calculateDay();
                    var workedTimeToday = Functions.convertSeconds(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[0].ToString()));
                    var extraTimeToday = Functions.convertSeconds(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[1].ToString()));
                    var festTimeToday = Functions.convertSeconds(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[2].ToString()));
                    if(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[0].ToString()) > 0    && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[1].ToString()) < 1 && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[2].ToString()) < 1)
                    {
                        debugLog11 = "\nHora de Salida\nNormal:"; //NORMAL
                        debugLog12 = "\n"+clockOut[3]+":"+clockOut[4]+":"+clockOut[5]+"\n"+workedTimeToday[1]+":"+workedTimeToday[2]+workedTimeToday[3];

                    }
                    else if(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[0].ToString()) > 0   && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[1].ToString()) > 0 && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[2].ToString()) < 1)
                    {
                        debugLog11 = "\nHora de Salida\nNormal:\nExtra:"; //NORMAL + EXTRA
                        debugLog12 = "\n"+clockOut[3]+":"+clockOut[4]+":"+clockOut[5]+"\n"+workedTimeToday[1]+":"+workedTimeToday[2]+workedTimeToday[3]+"\n"+extraTimeToday[0]+"-"+extraTimeToday[1]+":"+extraTimeToday[2]+":"+extraTimeToday[3];;

                    }
                    else if(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[0].ToString()) > 0 && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[1].ToString()) < 1 && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[2].ToString()) > 0)
                    {
                        debugLog11 = "\nHora de Salida\nNormal:\nFestivo:"; //NORMAL + FESTIVO
                        debugLog12 = "\n"+clockOut[3]+":"+clockOut[4]+":"+clockOut[5]+"\n"+workedTimeToday[1]+":"+workedTimeToday[2]+workedTimeToday[3]+"\n"+festTimeToday[0]+"-"+festTimeToday[1]+":"+festTimeToday[2]+":"+festTimeToday[3];

                    }
                    else if(parseInt(workedSecondsToday[0].ToString()) > 0 && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[1].ToString()) > 0 && parseInt(workedSecondsToday[2].ToString()) > 0)
                    {
                        debugLog11 = "\nHora de Salida\nNormal:\nExtra:\nFestivo:"; //NORMAL + EXTRA + FESTIVO
                        debugLog12 = "\n"+clockOut[3]+":"+clockOut[4]+":"+clockOut[5]+"\n"+workedTimeToday[1]+":"+workedTimeToday[2]+workedTimeToday[3]+"\n"+extraTimeToday[0]+"-"+extraTimeToday[1]+":"+extraTimeToday[2]+":"+extraTimeToday[3]+"\n"+festTimeToday[0]+"-"+festTimeToday[1]+":"+festTimeToday[2]+":"+festTimeToday[3];
                    }
                    clockedOut = true;
                    clockedIn = false;
                }
                else 
                {
                    debugLog01 = mainMsg;
                    debugLog11 = "\n"+errorMsg2;
                    debugLog12 = "\n";

                }
            }
```

Can't explain myself better since I have no clue about what is happening. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Debug your app on the android, and see what message prints in the LogCat.

Comment: Thank for the fast reply! I already tried this, but android debug monitor says “Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory”. And since i have never used android sdk, or eclipse or any of these apps y can't get it to run. Also tried with my gf's SGI with same result.

Comment: try with: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=17774398&postcount=93

Comment: If i dial this in my phone, i hear a woman saying "This number doesn't exist" and nothing happens. Thanks, tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday, i started placing tons of labels everywhere in my code and finally discovered where it stopped.

It was just replacing this...

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath+"\\Settings.txt", false);
```

by...

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(Application.persistentDataPath+"/Settings.txt", false);
```

Only windows supports this bar "\" when used for setting paths, but i was thinking all the time that the error was somewhere in the OnGUI function.

Thanks lot to everyone who came helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

On the Unity3D you can find this information:

```
Work with specific constraints (constraint):

Samsung Galaxy S (30 MB limit to downloadable file size, also problems with UI)
Samsung Galaxy Tab (30 MB limit to downloadable file size)
HTC Desire (40 MB limit to downloadable file size)
Samsung Galaxy S2 (Minor but possibly annoying issue: phone may work in 16-bit mode with Unity and show color banding Edit: a workaround was added to address the GS2 graphics driver, I don't know if it was related to this problem or not)
HTC EVO3D (Must build with Unity 3.4)
HTC Sensation (Must build with Unity 3.4)
```

**Samsung Galaxy S2 (Minor but possibly annoying issue: phone may work in 16-bit mode with Unity and show color banding Edit: a workaround was added to address the GS2 graphics driver, I don't know if it was related to this problem or not)**

[Unity3D Android Limitations](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/94919-Androids-that-do-NOT-work-with-Unity-Android-or-that-have-limitations)

Comment: The application runs on phone. The rest of the buttons look and work fine. Its just this couple of buttons depending each other which are not working as intended.

Comment: App is only 9MB and it's basically just a bunch of GUI elements.

Comment: it writes that there are issues with this phone: Samsung Galaxy S2

Comment: Tested it on SGI with same result. Also, the issue sounds like color issue, right? The app looks fine, and everything but those 2 buttons works fine. A friend told me that could be something about I/O, due to write permissions. We fixed this and now it generates the txt files that app uses in the SD Card.(it was something about dataPath vs persistentDataPath).